# Stored procedure for Search Products with words in any order

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck in  nopcommerce stored procedure for product search which is quiet big.So I cannot post code .But part of store procedure is

```
where 
   --Some conditions
AND (
                @SearchKeywords = 0 or 
                (
                patindex(@Keywords, p.name) > 0  
                    )
```

)

here I have converted my keyword to keyword with delimiter e.g 'gemini oil' to '%gemini%oil%' now if p.name is 'Gemini Refined Sunflower Oil' its working correctly.

But if my keyword is '%oil%gemini%' its not working.So basically I want to return result even if words in search keyword matches with p.name ,Condition is that words in search keyword can be any order.Contains slows down stored procedure so that option cannot work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763724/sql-select-like-keywords-in-any-order

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Full Text Search should help you out. You will basically create indexes on the columns you want to search. in the where clause of your query you will use the CONTAINS operator and pass it your search input.

you can start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx  or 
http://beingoyen.blogspot.in/2008/09/full-text-search-step-by-step-tutorial.html
to learn more

already answered in different post by stephen776

post here again to increase visibility

Comment: thanx,i am not very familiar with indexing will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You should create a fulltext index. That's what they are made for. You can then search in your column using the `contains` or `freetext` functions.

Warning: Fulltext search is very powerfull and you should get familiar with the possibilities and caveats (stopword lists!).